# Where is links__node__node() defined?

Tags: theming, navigation

I'm trying to figure out how I can alter the theme for read more links. This is what goes on inside the node.module ~ line 1380.

```
$node->content['links']['node'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'links__node__node',
  '#links' => $links,
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('links', 'inline')),
);
```

I know where are several ways to remove the read more links and add your own, but I just want to know where that theme function is stored and how I can override it like it can be done with fields using `theme_field()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function defined in include/theme.inc is [theme_links($variables)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_links/7); in your theme define `yourtheme_links($variables)`.

Answer (score 3):

The "`links__node__node`" theme function is not defined from any Drupal module. If a module defines a theme function matching that name, then Drupal will use it; otherwise, the function that is going to be used is [theme_links()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_links/7).

In your theme, you can define both the theme functions. The difference is that `theme_links()` is generally used, while the other theme function is used just in a specific case.

```
function themename_links__node__node(&$variables) {
  $links = $variables['links'];
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
  // …
}
```

```
function themename_links(&$variables) {
  $links = $variables['links'];
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
  $heading = $variables['heading'];
  // …
}
```